# How to remove "Toggle Downloadable" from WooCommerce Variations tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used the code below and the `Toggle Downloadable` is still visible under the dropdown option in Variations tab.

```
function my_remove_product_type_options( $options ) {
    if ( isset( $options['downloadable'] ) ) {
        unset( $options['downloadable'] );
    }
    return $options;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'my_remove_product_type_options' );
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSyAs.png)

Comment: Could you please show image, for example?

Comment: @Dmitry I just attached a screenshot.

Comment: You can try remove via javascript. I don't found hooks. Template path - `woocommerce >includes>meta-boxes>views>html-product-data-variations.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well been years not using woo, but I remember there was an option to remove them.

on `WooCommerce->Settings->Advanced` remove the entry for downloadable in the Account section, just leave it empty. All done, it shouldnt be displayed anymore.

**Option 2**

You can edit file manuall goto :includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-variations.php

Open file with notepad find line 60 and remove downloadable option.

```
<option value="toggle_downloadable"><?php esc_html_e( 'Toggle &quot;Downloadable&quot;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
```

See file here : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-variations.php

**NOTE :** Please backup your original file.

**Option 3**

Add jquery code to the page displaying select box

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{ 
 $("#field_to_edit option[value=toggle_downloadable]").hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field_to_edit">

 <option value="box1">BOX 1</option>
 <option value="box2">BOX 2</option>
 <option value="toggle_downloadable">downloadable</option>
 <option value="box3">BOX 3</option>
 <option value="box4">BOX 4</option>
 <option value="box5">BOX 5</option>

</select>
```